# Why the toast disappear for a while when jump to an activity with heavy layout?

Tags: android, toast

[image]

Click a button in the first page to show a toast and jump to the second page at the same time. The second page has heavy layout and Initialization which I knowI need to optimize (In the demo I use `Thread.sleep()` in the `onCreate` method of the second activity to simulate it).
I just want to know why the toast disappear for a while and reappear in the course of jumping.

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: which is code?? although.... if you put sleep it in the second activity, you are paralyzing the execution of the activity including the Toast